# How can I change the "References" to "Reference" in the thebibliography environment?

Tags: bibliographies, naming

My problem is that I have only one reference. So I would like the head of this part to appear "Reference" instead of commonly "References". More generally, could we change the title "References" to an arbitrary name?

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: For more complete answers, see [How to change the name of document elements like "Figure", "Contents", "Bibliography" etc.?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/82993)

Answer (score 127, accepted):

It depends on the documentclass.

```
\renewcommand\bibname{Reference}
```

works for some.

As chl points out. Others use `\refname` instead of `\bibname`.

Comment: (+1) Ah, we posted quite at the same time, but you the first :-) I just suggested in addition to replace `\refname` by `\bibname` for a `book`. Feel free to add it to your answer if you like.

Comment: To change ShareLatex name use `\renewcommand\refname{Reference}`.

Comment: You can pretty much tell whether you need refname or bibname by whether the current name is references or bibliography, respectively :-)

Comment: @JoannaBryson That's a good heuristic but sadly isn't always true. (It works for the standard document classes but a case-insensitive grep for `refname.*biblio` and `bibname.*reference` in my `texmf-dist/tex/latex` directory show a handful that don't follow that convention. Mainly dissertation formats, it seems.)

Comment: To my experience, some packages like babel may interfere with this command.

Comment: \renewcommand\refname worked for me. Using this in OverLeaf.

Answer (score 51):

In my case, I added the following option to `\printbibliography`:

```
\printbibliography[title={Reference}]
```

For more details, see the [BibLaTeX documentation](http://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex), section 3.7.2 The Bibliography.

Comment: Best and simplest answer ;)

Answer (score 32):

It seems `\refname` works fine for me while `\bibname` not.

For TOC, in case you need it, use `\contentsname`

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{whatever}
\renewcommand{\refname}{whatever}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! To make your answer more usable for others, it would very much help if you indicated *which* document class you use. (Some document classes use the macro `\bibname`, while others use `\refname`.)

Comment: You can pretty much tell whether you need refname or bibname by whether the current name is references or bibliography, respectively :-)

Answer (score 13):

In my case, I needed to add the following lines:

```
\usepackage[english,portuguese]{babel}
\addto\captionsportuguese{\renewcommand{\figurename}{Fig.}}
\addto\captionsportuguese{\renewcommand{\refname}{Reference}}
\renewcommand{\figurename}{Fig.}
\renewcommand{\refname}{Reference}
```

I hope this helps to complete this topic.

Comment: Welcome. When you type some code you can select it and press `ctrl+k` to format as code.

Comment: Thank you. This helped me too! In my case I had to replace portuguese with german. :)

Answer (score 10):

Renew the `\bibsection`-command. For example:

`\renewcommand{\bibsection}{\subsection*{Reference, typeset as un-numbered subsection.}}`

(Credits to http://latex.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=4089, where I found the solution which worked for me.)

Answer (score 5):

For cyrillic OT1 I found out this solution. hope it'll help.
add this to preamble:

`\addto\captionsrussian{\def\refname{Список литературы}}`

Answer (score 4):

What worked for me is an un-numbered chapter:

```
\renewcommand{\bibsection}{\chapter*{Publications and presentations}}
```

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on [Lucas Jardim's solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/244020/289820), the most voted solution doesn't work when using `babel` package as this package overwrites any `\refname` or `\bibname` configurations.

In order to get it working you just have to change it after importing `babel` package:

```tex
\usepackage[$LANGUAGE]{babel}
\addto\captions$LANGUAGE{\renewcommand{\refname}{$NEWREFNAME}}
%     \extras$LANGUAGE                 \bibname
```

where:

- `$LANGUAGE` is the language you want to use it for
- `$NEWREFNAME` is the new reference name you want to set

The alternatives (`extras` instead of `captions` and `\bibname` instead of `\refname`) were
written in the comment if the code doesn't work.

---

### Example for Polish language:

Where `$LANGUAGE = polish` and `$NEWREFNAME = Źródła`:

```tex
\usepackage[polish]{babel}
\addto\captionspolish{\renewcommand{\refname}{Źródła}}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
\renewcommand\bibname{Reference}


make sure to write this line at the beginning after you define your document class if you wanna change the default bibliography name to "Reference":
For example: 
\documentclass[12pt]{report}

\renewcommand\bibname{Reference}


\begin{document}

...
```