# How to change Bibliography heading?

Tags: sectioning, bibliographies

Let's take `article` document class with bibliography:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
Some text \cite{key01}.
\begin{thebibliography}{9}% 2nd arg is the width of the widest label.
\bibitem{key01}
Beeblebrox, Zaphod, Galactic University Press
etc. etc.`
\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

Above list of bibliography entries there is `References` which looks like generates with: `\section*{References}` .

I would like it to look like default text.

How to change it ?

Should I `\renewcommand` to overwrite default `\section` ? If yes, how to revert default `\section` later ? If other more elegant option exists, could you provide ?

(pdflatex)

Comment: If you just want to change the name of the section: http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=fixnam and http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17445/how-can-i-change-the-references-to-reference-in-the-thebibliography-environm

Comment: You should accept **Gonzalo**'s answer as it's way more elaborate and less prone to cause unexpected / unwanted behavior.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

<strike>You can use the `\let\store\macro` command, which saves the *current definition* of `\macro` to `\store`.</strike>

### The Code

```
\documentclass[parskip]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[margin=15mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\section{test}

\let\oldsection\section
\renewcommand*{\section}[1]{#1}

\section{new test}

\let\section\oldsection

\section{reverted?}

\end{document}
```

### The Output ##

[image]

---

**Edit 1:** Much easier, fully working approach: use options inside `\renewcommand{\refname}{}`.

### The Code

```
\documentclass[parskip]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[margin=15mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\section{test}

\renewcommand{\refname}{\normalfont\selectfont\normalsize References} 

\section{new test}

  \begin{thebibliography}{depth}
    \bibitem{atuning}Volker Wollny (Hrsg.): {\it Amiga--Tuning}.
                     Interest--Verlag, Augsburg, 1996.
  \end{thebibliography}

\section{reverted?}

\end{document}
```

### The Output

[image]

Comment: I like more your first solution; using the second approach you are also silently modifying possible headers since `\refname` is used to produce them, and this could not be desirable.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina: But the first one doesn't work properly: it prints `*References` instead of `References`, due to the bibliography using `section*` I think. However trying the `\let` course as before fails for `section*`.

Comment: You're right; first one doesn't work.

Answer (score 17):

One option would be to use the `titlesec` package to locally redefine the section formatting:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\begin{document}

\section{Test Section One}

\begingroup
\titleformat*{\section}{\normalfont}
\begin{thebibliography}{depth}
\bibitem{a} Test
\end{thebibliography}
\endgroup

\section{Test Section Two}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Another option is to patch the `\thebibliography` command to replace the default `\section*{\refname}` with `\refname`; this can be easily done with the help of the `etoolbox` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\patchcmd{\thebibliography}{\section*{\refname}}{\refname}{}{}

\begin{document}

\section{Test Section One}

\begin{thebibliography}{depth}
\bibitem{a} Test
\end{thebibliography}

\section{Test Section Two}

\end{document}
```

Without any packages, the necessary redefinition would be:

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\renewenvironment{thebibliography}[1]
     {\refname%
      \@mkboth{\MakeUppercase\refname}{\MakeUppercase\refname}%
      \list{\@biblabel{\@arabic\c@enumiv}}%
           {\settowidth\labelwidth{\@biblabel{#1}}%
            \leftmargin\labelwidth
            \advance\leftmargin\labelsep
            \@openbib@code
            \usecounter{enumiv}%
            \let\p@enumiv\@empty
            \renewcommand\theenumiv{\@arabic\c@enumiv}}%
      \sloppy
      \clubpenalty4000
      \@clubpenalty \clubpenalty
      \widowpenalty4000%
      \sfcode`\.\@m}
     {\def\@noitemerr
       {\@latex@warning{Empty `thebibliography' environment}}%
      \endlist}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\section{Test Section One}

\begin{thebibliography}{depth}
\bibitem{a} Test
\end{thebibliography}

\section{Test Section Two}

\end{document}
```

The last two examples produce the same output as the first one, so I didn't upload the repeated images.