# Change BibTeX's language

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, languages, greek

I am writing a document in Greek.

My bibliography, however consists mainly of English entries (along with a few Greek, French and German ones).

If I just add the `.bib` file all entries are in Greek. If I change language before adding the `.bib` file entries are in English, so is the chapter title, which is not prefered in my case.
I tried using

```
\selectlanguage{english}
```

on the very first line of my `.bib` file but it didn't work.
I also tried

```
\LANGUAGE=english
```

as a field in the bibliography entry, but it didn't work either...
Any ideas?

Here follows my `.tex` files (I am using `subfiles`) and the `.bib` file.

`main.tex`

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[english,greek]{babel}
\usepackage[iso-8859-7]{inputenc}
\usepackage{kerkis}
\usepackage{subfiles}
\usepackage[Glenn]{fncychap}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

%!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
\usepackage{tocloft}
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\tocwithouttitle}{\@starttoc{toc}}
\makeatother
%--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\lofwithouttitle}{\@starttoc{lof}}
\makeatother
%--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\lotwithouttitle}{\@starttoc{lot}}
\makeatother
%--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

\parskip 3mm
\footskip = 15mm
\begin{document}

%~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~Front-Page~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
\begin{titlepage}
Frontpage
\end{titlepage}

\pagenumbering{roman}

\textcolor{Darkblue}{\chapter*{\contentsname}}
\markboth{\MakeUppercase{\contentsname}}{\MakeUppercase{\contentsname}}
\textcolor{Darkblue}{\tocwithouttitle}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Περιεχόμενα}

\newpage

\textcolor{Darkblue}{\chapter*{Κατάλογος Σχημάτων}}
\markboth{\MakeUppercase{Κατάλογος Σχημάτων}}{\MakeUppercase{Κατάλογος Σχημάτων}}
\textcolor{Darkblue}{\lofwithouttitle}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Κατάλογος Σχημάτων}

\newpage

\textcolor{Darkblue}{\chapter*{Κατάλογος Πινάκων}}
\markboth{\MakeUppercase{Κατάλογος Πινάκων}}{\MakeUppercase{Κατάλογος Πινάκων}}
\textcolor{Darkblue}{\lotwithouttitle}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Κατάλογος Πινάκων}

\newpage

\pagenumbering{arabic}

\subfile{introductionGR.tex}

\clearpage
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Βιβλιογραφία}
%\selectlanguage{english}
\textcolor{Darkblue}{\bibliography{test}}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\end{document}
```

This is my subfile (named `introductionGR.tex`) with citations...

```
\documentclass[main.tex]{subfiles}
\begin{document}
\textcolor{Darkblue}{\chapter{Εισαγωγή}}
Ο κόσμος στον οποίο ζούμε είναι αποτέλεσμα βίαιων διεργασιών που έλαβαν χώρα πριν από     περίπου $14$ δισεκατομύρια χρόνια\cite{UniverseAge}. Η φυσική υψηλών ενεργειών ή   σωματιδιακή φυσικής βρίσκεται\cite{bar2} στο προσκήνιο 
\end{document}
```

Last but not least my `.bib` file (named `test.bib`)

```
\selectlanguage{english}
@article{UniverseAge,
    author    = "N. Jarosik et al",
    title     = "Seven-year Wilkinson Microwave Anisotropy Probe (WMAP) Observations: Sky Maps, Systematic Errors, and Basic Results",
    journal   = "The Astrophysical Journal Supplement Series",
    volume   = "192",
    number   = "14",
    pages    = "15",
    year      = "2011",
    month    = "February",
}

@BOOK{bar2,
    AUTHOR = "Astar, R. M.",
    TITLE = "Foo Bar Baz",
    PUBLISHER = {MIT Press},
    ADDRESS = {Cambridge, MA},
    YEAR = 1989}
```

I have also tried `package babellib` but it's not working either...
The code I used:

```
 \usepackage{babelbib}
 \selectbiblanguage{english}
```

Note: I don't want to use XeLaTeX. Isn't it possible?

---

Error #1:

```
LaTeX Error:Command \c@lofdepth already defined.
            Or name \end...illegal, see p.192 of the manual.
See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
```

The line that has a problem is

```
\newcounter{lofdeth}
```

which is in a subfigure file!(?)

Error #2:

```
LaTeX Error:Command \c@lofdepth already defined.
            Or name \end...illegal, see p.192 of the manual.
See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
```

The line that has a problem is

```
\newcounter{lotdeth}
```

which is in a subfigure file!(?)

Error #3:

```
LaTeX Error:Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.
See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
```

The line that has a problem is

```
\contentsline {chapter}{Perieq'omena}{\textlatin {iii}}{chapter*.1}
```

which is in main.toc

Note: `Perieq'omena` is the Greeklish word for Contents. The correct word would be `Περιεχόμενα`.

Error #4:

```
LaTeX Error:Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.
See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
```

The line that has a problem is

```
\addvspace {10\p@ }
```

which is in main.lof

Error #5:

```
LaTeX Error:Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.
See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
```

The line that has a problem is

```
\addvspace {10\p@ }
```

which is in main.lot

I think that Error #3 might have a connection to my issue.
I am using kerkis font.
But the problems remains even if I use the default babel one.

---

Warnings for MWE

Warning #1:

```
LaTeX Font Warnig:Some font shapes were not available,defaults substituded.
```

Warning #2:

```
LaTeX Font Warnig: Font shape 'OT1/MAK/m/n' undefined
                   using 'OT1/cmr/m/n' instead on input line 1
```

Warning #3:

```
LaTeX Warnig: Overwriting file './test.bib'
```

Comment: I just came across an idea... I used `\renewcommand\bibname{Βιβλιογραφία}` where "Βιβλιογραφία" is the name I want, along with `\selectlanguage{english}` before adding the `.bib` file but it didn't work...

Comment: check out http://www.mechpedia.gr/wiki/LaTeX

Comment: I don't use XeLaTeX...I want to  do that in LaTeX...

Answer (score 6):

You have several errors in your files. First of all your MWE does not compile. Make a MWE as small as possible. Delete everything not relevant to the problem.

In your `bib` file add a field `language={English}` for each entry, if the language is English. For a Greek book/article/... add `language={Greek}`.

Your `\textcolor{Darkblue}{\tocwithouttitle}` does not compile. First of all the color `Darkblue` is not definded (`\usepackage[]{xcolor}` missing?). I deleted it.

In your `bib` file you have `author    = "N. Jarosik et al",`. You should write all authors into your `bib` file including complete firstnames; it depends on the style of your bibliography wheater to print a list of authors or "first author et al".

**Update 1 and 2:**

Package `filecontents` writes the file `test.bib` (our minimal `bib` file). With `texdoc filecontents` you can read the package documentation. With `\selectlanguage{...}` you can switch the language. Please note that I changed the document class to `report` just to get a shorter `pdf` file.

A shorter MWE (on my system it is compiling):

```
%https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/69780/change-bibtexs-language
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{test.bib}
@comment Datei test.bib
@article{UniverseAge,
    author    = "N. Jarosik et al",
    title     = "Seven-year Wilkinson Microwave Anisotropy Probe (WMAP) Observations: Sky Maps, Systematic Errors, and Basic Results",
    journal   = "The Astrophysical Journal Supplement Series",
    volume   = "192",
    number   = "14",
    pages    = "15",
    year      = "2011",
    month    = "February",
    language = "English",
}

@BOOK{bar2,
    AUTHOR    = {Astar, R. M.},
    TITLE     = {Foo Bar Baz},
    PUBLISHER = {MIT Press},
    ADDRESS   = {Cambridge, MA},
    language  = {English},
    YEAR      = {1989}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[english,greek]{babel}
\usepackage[iso-8859-7]{inputenc}
%\usepackage[T1,OT1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{kerkis}

\begin{document}

\selectlanguage{greek}
\tableofcontents

\section*{Κατάλογος Πινάκων}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Κατάλογος Πινάκων}

\section{Εισαγωγή}
δισεκατομύρια χρόνια\cite{UniverseAge}. ... βρίσκεται\cite{bar2} στο προσκήνιο

\selectlanguage{english}
\renewcommand\bibname{Βιβλιογραφία}
%\renewcommand{\bibname}{\normalsize Βιβλιογραφία} 
%\renewcommand\bibname{{\fontfamily{mak}\selectfont Βιβλιογραφία}}
%\renewcommand\bibname{{\usefont{T1}{mak}{m}{n} Βιβλιογραφία}}  % T1,OT1
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{test}

\end{document}
```

I added some commented line to show alternatives you have and you should play with. 
For example, do you use `fontenc`? I added two alternatives to switch the heading of your bibliography.

Also have a look to the question [how-to-change-bibliography-heading](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/69224/how-to-change-bibliography-heading).

If this MWE is running you can compare it with your thesis at find out the differences between both. Have a look to this differences and copy small parts from your thesis into the MWE, recompile and check what's happend. No errors? Good, next part ...

Comment: First of all... I supposse that lines before `\begin{document}` are the .bib file... I added all your extra code to my .bib file, I compiled it but it didn't work...Bib entries are in Greek, not in English...

Comment: I also tried to use that code before `\documentclass[]{}`, in the exact way as your code implies. The output is exactly the same , I'm afraid...No bib entries at all...

Comment: It's not working... Or should I say it is partially working? Entries are in English, however title is in Greek-lish, meaning that it is indeed the Greek word, in latin letters though...

Comment: I used `\renewcommand\bibname{\fontfamily{mak}\selectfont Βιβλιογραφία}` just after `\selectlanguage{english}` but again it is not working... I also tried to put `\selectlanguage{english}` just before `bibliography{test}` but it doesn't work either...

Comment: It's not working either...I'll use an answer just to show my errors and warnigns...

Comment: This is also true for you MWE... I get `0 Errors` and `3 Warnings`...See my first question for details...

Comment: In case it helps...I am having the exact same problem with Adobe Reader's bookmarks and `Conny` `chapter style`...

Comment: I am using `LaTeX` in Windows `Vista` and I can't find out my `bibtex` version... To create `bib` file I am just editing an empty document, naming it `XXX.bib`...

Comment: I am using `MikTex-pdftex 2.8.3759<1.40.10><MikTex 2.8>` and `MikTex-bibtex 2.8.3518 <0.99c><MikTex 2.8>`.