# Change alignment locally inside a tabular cell

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment

I want to align some specific cells inside a `LaTeX` table. I tried using `center enviroment` inside cell, but it didn't work-`Error: Undefined Control Sequence \begin{center}`. I also tried with `\centering` which produces no errors, however it doesn't do the job. My MWE is the following

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[english,greek]{babel}
\usepackage[iso-8859-7]{inputenc}
\usepackage{kerkis}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{units}
\usepackage{array}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[H]
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{l r r r}
\hline
{} & {\centering \textbf{Ενέργεια}} & {\centering \textbf{Ενέργεια}} & {\centering     \textbf{Μέσος Αριθμός}}\\
{\textbf{Αέριο}} & {\centering \textbf{Διέγερσης}} & {\centering \textbf{Ιονισμού}} &     {\centering \textbf{Παραγωγής Ζεύγους}}\\
{} & {\centering $[eV]$} & {\centering $[eV]$} & {}\\
\hline
{} & {} & {} & {} \\
{$Ar$} & {$11.6$} & {$15.8$} & {$26$} \\
{$CO_2$} & {$10.0$} & {$13.7$} & {$33$} \\
{$CH_4$} & {$12.6$} & {$14.5$} & {$28$} \\
{$Kr$} & {$10.0$} & {$14.0$} & {$24$} \\
{$Xe$} & {$8.4$} & {$12.1$} & {$22$} \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{Μέσος αριθμός παραγωγής ζεύγους για διάφορα αέρια}
\label{tab:Excitation-Ionization}
\end{center}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Ενέργεια}}` for the first cell you want to treat in a special way and similarly for the others. You *don't* need braces around the cell contents.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! As far as braces are concerned I am having a template, I pasted and I just forgot to delete them...!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Update

Usage of the option `LGRx` is not needed any longer.

---

A single cell alignment can be changed with `\multicolumn{1}{c}{...}` (for centering it).

However I suggest you some improvements to your table:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[LGRx,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,greek]{babel}

\usepackage{kerkis}

\usepackage{array,booktabs}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{unit-mode=math}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{>{\fontencoding{T1}\selectfont}l *{2}{S[table-format=2.1]}S[table-format=2]}
\toprule
\multicolumn{1}{l}{\textbf{Αέριο}} &
 \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Ενέργεια}} &
 \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Ενέργεια}} &
 \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Μέσος Αριθμός}} \\
 &
 \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Διέγερσης}} &
 \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Ιονισμού}} &
 \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Παραγωγής Ζεύγους}} \\
 &
 \multicolumn{1}{c}{(\si{\electronvolt})} &
 \multicolumn{1}{c}{(\si{eV})} & \\
\midrule
Ar & 11.6 & 15.8 & 26 \\
CO$_2$ & 10.0 & 13.7 & 33 \\
CH$_4$ & 12.6 & 14.5 & 28 \\
Kr & 10.0 & 14.0 & 24 \\
Xe & 8.4 & 12.1 & 22 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\caption{Μέσος αριθμός παραγωγής ζεύγους για διάφορα αέρια}
\label{tab:Excitation-Ionization}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

I'd prefer UTF-8 to ISO-8859-7, also if it requires some juggling for typesetting Latin text.

Element symbols should be upright, as units. With `siunitx` it's easy to get correct alignment of numbers. Note the two alternative ways to express the eV unit.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer...I am afraid that your code isn't working on my system... I cannot use `utf8 encoding` let alone despite succesfully installing `siunitx`...

Comment: @Thanos The `\multicolumn{1}{c}{...}` bit is surely working, though.

Comment: Yes, it does! But I think that `siunitx` is a great package...While I am trying to use it I get `File 'exp13.sty' not found`, despite having already installed package `siunitx`...

Comment: Quite frankly, though, your output is much better than mine!Realy cool!!! Is there a way to do it? I supose I really need `siunitx`... As far as the encoding is concerned, I have a hunch that `utf8` may solve other issues like http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/69780/change-bibtexs-language

Comment: @Thanos You really need to upgrade your TeX distribution.

Comment: You really think so...?The thing is that I am on the middle of writing my thesis, so I would prefer not to risk it at the moment...

Comment: @Thanos That's really a good justification; but then you have to bear with the limitations of your current TeX distribution.

Comment: That is a good point... I'll try to upgrade as soon as I will finish my thesis!Thank you!!!