# Can't change bibliography heading

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, xetex

I would like to change the heading of my bibliography. I found this thread: [How to change Bibliography heading?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/69224/how-to-change-bibliography-heading)

Unfortunately, this doesn't work for me. Additionally, I would like to remove the page header 'LITERATUR'.

```
\documentclass[landscape]{article}

% paper geometry
\usepackage[landscape]{geometry}
\geometry{
    a4paper,
    total={210mm,297mm},
    left=15mm,
    right=15mm,
    top=15mm,
    bottom=20mm
}

% header and footer
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancyfoot[LO, RE] {Test}
\fancyfoot[C]{-\,\thepage\,-}
% columns

\usepackage{multicol}
\columnseprule0.5pt
\columnsep5mm

% german spelling
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage[babelshorthands=true]{german}

% citation
\usepackage{cite}
\bibliographystyle{ieeetr}
% change heading of bibliography
\renewcommand{\refname}{Literaturverzeichnis}

% blind text for mwe
\usepackage{blindtext}


\begin{document}

\begin{multicols}{4}
\section*{Test}
\blindtext
Test \cite{wiki:test}
\blindtext

\bibliography{references}

\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I compile this tex file with:

```
xelatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode test
bibtex test
xelatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode test
xelatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode test
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `babel` or `polyglossia` for language support, you need to add the `\renewcommand` for the bibliography name to the elements defined by `babel` or `polyglossia`.

```
\addto\captionsgerman{\renewcommand{\refname}{Literaturverzeichnis}}
```

It's not quite clear from your question what the problem is with the page headings. In your original code, you don't set any specific header code, so the default is used (which is what you are seeing). If you only want this header for the bibliography pages, you can set the header inside the above command:

```
\addto\captionsgerman{
   \renewcommand{\refname}{Literaturverzeichnis}
   \fancyhead {MyHead}}
```

Here's your complete code:

```
\documentclass[landscape]{article}

% paper geometry
\usepackage[landscape]{geometry}
\geometry{
    a4paper,
    total={210mm,297mm},
    left=15mm,
    right=15mm,
    top=15mm,
    bottom=20mm
}

% header and footer
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancyfoot[LO, RE] {Test}
\fancyfoot[C]{-\,\thepage\,-}
% columns

\usepackage{multicol}
\columnseprule0.5pt
\columnsep5mm

% german spelling
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage[babelshorthands=true]{german}

% citation
\usepackage{cite}
\bibliographystyle{ieeetr}
% change heading of bibliography
\addto\captionsgerman{%
  \renewcommand{\refname}{Literaturverzeichnis}
  \fancyhead{MyHead}}

% blind text for mwe
\usepackage{blindtext}


\begin{document}

\begin{multicols}{4}
\section*{Test}
\blindtext
Test \cite{wiki:test}
\blindtext

\bibliography{references}

\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you. on the page where the bibliography appears the header shows "LITERATURVERZEICHNIS", however I'd like to have a custom header on this page.

Comment: @konze I've updated the answer now. Perhaps this is what you need?  (Also, note that I've used the `\addto` macro instead of `\gappto`; the result is the same, but the former is more consistent between `babel` and `polyglossia`.