# Using nocite for printing selective bibliography with chapterbib

Tags: bibliographies, natbib, chapterbib

I am using `\nocite` with [`chapterbib`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/chapterbib) for selective bibliographies to be printed at the end of each chapter. It would be very kind of you if the usage of `\nocite` with `chapterbib` is explained.

I have two issues with this

1. `\nocite` is printing selective bibliography at the end of the chapters but I am not sure if I have to use `\cite` command at the citation because in the text/body of the chapter the citations are not shown.
2. How can I change the title "bibliography"to "references" when I print it.

I am using `natbib`.

Kindly help.

Comment: The `\nocite` command is for the case where you want a reference to show up in the bibliography _without_ a citation in the text. If you want the citation to show in the text you should use `\cite` instead (no need for `\nocite` as well). For changing the title, see [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17445/how-can-i-change-the-references-to-reference-in-the-thebibliography-environm).

Comment: This question cannot be answered right now. Please post a minimal working example, so we can reproduce your situation.

Answer (score 1):

1. If you want the citation to appear in the text, then use `\cite` and not `\nocite`, as the name says **no cite** will not print the citation in the text.
2. As for changing the title, this depends on which bibliography tool you use. Based on [your previous question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/331558/using-natbib-with-inputenc-all-citations-show-and-few-of-the-equations-a) I would assume `biblatex`, but in this question you write that you use `natbib` which implies `bibtex`, so I'm a bit confused -- nevertheless, for `biblatex` it would be `\printbibliography[title={References}]`.