# Problem with heading

Tags: bibliographies

I am using JabRef for my reference in LaTeX.

But the heading for this section is "Bibliography", instead of "References".
Commands used in latex:

```
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{REFERENCES(this is my bib file)}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!

Comment: JabRef does not really have a lot of say in how the heading of your bibliography/list of references is produced. That is usually controlled by the document class you are using. Maybe https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/82993/35864 or  https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/17445/35864 can help you. If those standard approaches all do not work, then it stands to reason that you are using a special class which needs special treatment. In that case it would help us if you could tell us more about your document by showing us a short, but compilable example document that reproduces what you get.