# How to remove the "s" in "References"?

Tags: bibliographies

I have tried the code:

```
\begin{thebibliography}{0}
\bibitem{item1}
author 1 and author 2
\textit{The title}.
Thesis. SchoolName, 2018.
\end{thebibliography}
```

It outputs "References", but since I am using only one reference, I want to use "Reference"; that is, without the "s".

**EDIT**
I used \documentclass{article}. What worked for me was using

```
\renewcommand\refname{Reference}
```

Comment: This will depend on your document class and possibly also on whether or not you load `babel` or `polyglossia`. An answer that is guaranteed to work for you can only be found if we get to see a full minimal example document (a so-called https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864) and not just code snippets. Anyway, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/17445/35864 and https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/82993/35864 might already be enough for you.

Comment: To be clear, if this snippet is in an `article` document class,  `\renewcommand\refname{Reference}`. In case of a `book` class `\renewcommand\bibname{Reference}`. Otherwise, who knows ...

Comment: thank you guys!!!