"references" show up when displaying bibliography
I'm extremely green when it comes to using Latex and am trying to use it via Overleaf for my resume. When citing my bib file for publications (refs.bib) everything shows up correctly, but this header "References" shows up as well and won't go away without removing the reference to the bib file.

This is what my code for this section looks like:
\section{Publications} 
\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\bibliography{refs}
\nocite{*}

How can I remove the "References" header? Any pointers would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Traditionally, the command \bibliography will produce a bibliography/list of references and a suitable section header. The exact format of that header is controlled by your document class, your language setup and any bibliography/citation-related packages you load. You are much more likely to receive a helpful and useful answer if you can tell us about these settings in a form of a small example document that reproduces the output from the screenshot with as little code as possible (the document should compile on our machines and should not reference files we don't have).

Instead of "Removing the References header", what you should do is to remove \section{Publications} and force \bibliography{refs} to generate Publications instead of References. For that, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/17445/119 and https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12597/renaming-the-bibliography-page-using-bibtex // Chances are you can replace \section{Publications} with \renewcommand\refname{Publications} and have it work, but I can't be sure without seeing your document class etc.

I suspect this is what you are looking for:
\renewcommand*{\refname}{Publications} 
\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\bibliography{refs}
\nocite{*}

Note that if you are using report or book, then replace \refname with \bibname.


With \printbibliography[heading=none]
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}

\nocite{aksin}

\printbibliography[heading=none]
    
\end{document}

